# Problema ao executar apps por wireless no android studio

Tags: android-studio

Estou com o problema de não conseguir usar a função Wireless do ADB para conseguir builder e debugar sem necessitar de cabo USB.

Eu utilizava normalmente plugins e nunca tive problema, porém não sei se foi por causa da atualização para Android 8.1.

Segue os passos que realizo atualmente:

```bsh
$ ./adb kill-server
$ ./adb tcpip 5555
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

$ ./adb connect 192.168.0.107:5555
failed to connect to '192.168.0.107:5555': Operation timed out
```

<sup>*Executo esses passos dentro da pasta platform-tools do android em um MacBook Pro*</sup>

Já verifiquei as opções de desenvolvimento e estão da mesma forma que funcionava anteriormente.

Comment: Ola @Diego, editei sua pergunta para dar destaque em seus passos realizados, por isso removi toda a informação extra do seu terminal, caso seja necessário você pode reverter essa edição [nesta pagina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/401405/revisions). =D

Comment: Ah, perfeito. Muito obrigado ;).